# Saving a signed XML With JavaScript in Google Chrome Browser - Visual basic back End

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

After signing an XML file via google Chrome, I am trying to save the signed one in an certain location. But I even cant get there, my code throws an exception from the beginning: My back End Code looks like this:

If hidBrowser.Value = "GoogleChrome" Then

```
        Dim xmlSign As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        Dim xmlRet As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument 'XmlElement
        Dim xmlRoot As XmlNode

        
        xmlSign.LoadXml(txtXML.Text)
        MyAlert(txtXML.Text)
```

End If

Comment: i forgot to post the exception: 

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$txtXML="<NewDataSet Id="Data...").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my asp page, where I put the code to digitally sign an XML with google chrome, in the  beginning <%Page .... among other properties I did put the atribute ValidateRequest="false"

Answer (score 0):

I put ValidateRequest="false" in my aspx page, And the problem was solved

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.